# How to show that the linear mappings $\phi_\mu^\nu$ generates the set $L(E;V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the book of *Linear Algebra By Werner Greub* at p 76, to show that $$\dim L(E;F) = \dim E \times \dim F$$, it constructs a map $\phi_\mu^\nu : E \to F$ by

$$\phi_\sigma^\lambda (x_\nu) = \delta_\nu^\lambda y_\sigma$$, and claims that these maps forms a basis for $L(E;F)$, but it doesn't give and proof to show that these are linearly independent maps, I'm trying to prove this.

> How to show that the linear mappings $\phi_\mu^\nu$ generates the set
>   $L(E;V)$

To show that $$\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu = 0_{L(E;V)}$$, we need to show that $$(\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu)(x) = 0\quad \forall x\in E$$

I actually made a proof about it, and I was writing here, so that you can check for any flow, but I have found a mistake during the writing, so how can we prove this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick it up from where you left off: let's prove that the mappings $\phi_\mu^\nu$ are *linearly independent*.

We want to show that if $\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu = 0_{L(E;V)}$, then all coefficients must be zero. That is, we need to show that 
$$
\left(\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu\right)(x) = 0\quad \forall x\in E \implies  \alpha_{\mu}^\nu = 0 \quad \forall \mu, \nu
$$
With that, we can plug in $x = x_\mu$ and note that
$$
\left(\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu\right)(x_\sigma) = 
\sum_{\mu}\alpha^\sigma_\mu x_\mu = 0
$$
However, the vectors $x_\mu$ form a basis, so we conclude that $\alpha^\sigma_\mu = 0$ for all $\mu$.  Noting that $\sigma$ was also arbitrary, we conclude that every $\alpha_\mu^\sigma = 0$.

---

Now, there's the separate questions of showing that these maps *generate the set $L(E;F)$*.   That is: given an arbitrary map $\phi:E \to F$, we want to show that there exist coefficients such that
$$
\phi = \sum_{\mu,\nu} \alpha_\mu^\nu \phi_\mu^\nu
$$
The proof is as follows: again, write out $\left(\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu\right)(x_\sigma)$.  By the definition of a basis, there is a unique set of coefficients $\alpha_\mu^\nu$ that guarantee these equations hold.

With that, we want to show that under these constraints, we have $\phi = \sum \alpha_\mu^\nu \phi_\mu^\nu$.  To that end, it suffices to note that these are two linear maps which act the same way on a basis.

Comment: but you need to show the result holds **for all x**, not just for the basis.Of course you can write any x as a linear combination of the basis, but when the coefficient in that linear combination comes into play in $\left(\sum_{\nu, \mu}\alpha_\mu^\nu\phi_\mu^\nu\right)(x) = 0\quad \forall x\in E \implies  \alpha_{\mu}^\nu = 0 \quad \forall \mu, \nu$, it just doesn't directly imply that  $\alpha_\mu^\sigma = 0.$

Comment: @Leth you have the direction of the proof wrong. You **know** that the map is zero for all $x$, and you want to conclude that the coefficients are zero.

Comment: exactly which point is wrong, I didn't get it, we are saying the same thing ?

Comment: You're saying that our goal is to *conclude* that the map is zero for all $x$.  I'm saying we *assume* that the map is zero for all $x$, and our goal is to conclude that the coefficients are zero

Comment: If the map is zero for all x, then that map cannot be in the bases of any vector space! Note that, we want to show the linear independence, and to do this we assume that a linear combination of the elements are zero, and conclude that this can happen only when all the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @Leth so now it sounds like we're saying the same thing, but I don't understand where you disagree with my proof. I show that $\alpha_\mu^\sigma=0$ for every $\mu,\sigma$.

Comment: Ok, first of all, in your previous comment you have said "'m saying we assume that the map is zero for all x
x
, and our goal is to conclude that the coefficients are zero", which disagrees with what I'm saying.Secondly, your proof is not complete.I mean you are show the linear independence just when $x = x_\nu$, i.e just for the bases, but it has to be valid **for all x**, so I'm saying that, you need to show that the maps are lin. independent for x's other than any bases element.

Comment: @Leth You're misunderstanding some basic definitions here.  What do you think it means to say that "the maps are lin independent when $x = x_\nu$"?  Notice, in fact, that as long as $\dim E > 1$, the outputs $\phi_\mu^\nu(x_\sigma)$ are **not** all linearly independent.

Comment: @Leth I am telling you (and you should feel free to verify this with your teacher) that when we say "the maps $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ are linearly independent" (say $f_i:E \to F$), what we mean is that
$$
\alpha_1 f_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n f_n = 0 \implies \alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0
$$
Notice that the equality on the left (the equality which we *assume*) is an equality of *maps*, one that holds for all inputs $x \in E$.

Comment: But this is exactly what I'm saying, but in your proof, you **just** showed that this equality holds for the bases of  the domain, **not for all x.**

Comment: I didn't **show** that  equality at all. I **used** that equality to show that the coefficients are zero.

Comment: While writing and response to your last comment, I realised what I'm missing, so the problem is solved.

Comment: @Leth glad to hear it. is there a way I could have been clearer? Anything I said that helped?

Comment: What I was missing was that we assumed some linear combination of those maps is equal to zero map, so that equality holds for all x, this was our **assumption**, so since it holds for all x, I we plug in $x = x_\nu$, it should also hold.In your last sentence, saying that we didn't show that equality holds allow me to realised our assumption, so if you have said that as I have said above "so that equality holds for all x, this was our assumption, so since it holds for all x, I we plug in $x = x_\nu$, it should also hold", it could have been clearer.